# No editors installed to fix sources list

Tags: programming, software-sources, text-editor

I 'm in Ubuntu 12.04 but I'm using it with crouton in a Chromebook, the terminal emulator it uses is `UXTerm` but it seems that it doesn't have any editor installed - gedit, nano and pico are all absent.

Because I messed up the `sources.list` I can't install any text editor through `apt-get` and therefore I can't fix the `sources.list`.

Comment: The editor `nano` will always be there.

Comment: What about `vi`? Have you tried booting via live CD? What error does `nano` give?

Comment: when I try `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`  it goes `sudo: nano: commando not found`

Comment: Good idea @Tim, `vi` appears to be working, thanks

Comment: @Tim: convert to an answer so people like me hunting for unanswered questions don't find this one unanswered?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `vi`:

```
vi
```

```
vim - Vi IMproved, a programmers text editor
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't find an editor, but can run `sudo` and `sh` (or `bash`), then use (replacing `trusty` with `precise` for 12.04, and `us` with an appropriate country code):

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
sudo sh -c 'printf "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty%s main multiverse restricted universe\n" "" -security -updates > /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

This uses only shell utilities (except for `mv`, and that isn't necessary), so it should be enough to rebuild your sources at least.